# mvc3: html.beginform search returning empty querystring

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, query-string, html.beginform

In an MVC3 app, i have the following View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Search", new {query = @Request.QueryString["query"]}, FormMethod.Post))
{
   <input type="search" name="query" id="query" value="" />
}
```

When i type in the url "/Search?query=test", Request.Querystring in my Index action reads out the search-value perfectly well (i have my routes set to ignore the Action in the url). When i type it in the seachbox, it hits the right action and controller (so the routing seems fine) but the querystring remains empty. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Problem is that you are look in the `Request.QueryString` collection. But you are doing a `POST` so the `query` value is in the `Request.Form` Collection. But i think you want your TextBox filled with the data so can do it like in my sample.

#### Sample

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
   <input type="search" name="query" id="query" value="@Request.Form["query"]" />
}
```

#### But this is not the real MVC approach. You should create a ViewModel for that.

**Model**

```
namespace MyNameSpace.Models
{
    public class SearchViewModel
    {
        public string Query { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**View**

```
@model MyNameSpace.Models.SearchViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
   @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Query)
   <input type="submit" />
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(new SearchViewModel());
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(SearchViewModel model)
{
    // do your search
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: hi dknaack, thanks for ur quick reply.. im afraid changing the order order of the parameters doesnt make a difference..

Comment: hi dknaack, that did the trick! its in Request.Form. thanks! and for what do you mean i should make a ViewModel?

Comment: @jim it does. But the ViewModel solution is the real answer.

Comment: dknaack, thanks for your extensive reply. ill go and implement your real MVC example :)