# FormMethod.Post to return querystring in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I passed my querystring in _Layout.cshtml page

```
  <li>@Html.ActionLink("Shopping", "Index1", new { controller = "Shopping", UserID = "Admin1" })</li>
```

I have an update view to update the values from textbox

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "Shopping", new { id = Request.QueryString["UserID"] }, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "myForm" }))
         {
               @Html.Hidden("id", @Request.QueryString["UserID"] as string)
               @Html.Hidden("productid", item.ProductID as string)
               @Html.TextBox("qty", item.Quantity)
               @Html.Hidden("unitrate", item.Rate)
               <input type="submit" value="Update" />
         }
```

In the first time post , i get the url like this

```
http://localhost:61110/Shopping/Index1?UserID=Admin1
```

But for the second time, after post i get the url like this

```
http://localhost:61110/Shopping/Index1
```

How to get the querystring value at all times when it the form is posted.

I also tried this [mvc3: html.beginform search returning empty querystring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9279741/mvc3-html-beginform-search-returning-empty-querystring)

But couldnt get the querystring on second time post 
Any suggestions.

EDIT : Update Action Code

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Update(string id, string productid, int qty, decimal unitrate)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                int _records = UpdatePrice(id,productid,qty,unitrate);
                if (_records > 0)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index1", "Shopping",new { id = Request.QueryString["UserID"] });
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("","Can Not Update");
                }
            }
            return View("Index1");
        }

public int UpdatePrice(string id,string productid,int qty,decimal unitrate)
    {
        con.Open(); 
        var total = qty * unitrate;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Update [Table_name] Set Quantity='" + qty + "',Price='" + total + "' where [User ID]='" + id + "' and [Product ID]='" + productid + "'", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@total", total);
        return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your `Update` action code? And how should the url look like after the post? Like `http://localhost:61110/Shopping/Index1?UserID=Admin1`? So do you want to keep the `UserID=Admin1` part?

Comment: I need the url to post with the querystring http://localhost:61110/Shopping/Index1?UserID=Admin1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `new { id = Request.QueryString["UserID"] }` to the RedirectToAction in Update as well.

Comment: I passed the value in RedirectToAction method. The value is null when it comes to view here .@using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "Shopping", new {id = Request.QueryString["UserID"] }, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "myForm" }))

Comment: @kk1076 - The code you posted above does not have the route values on the RedirectToAction in the Update method.  Also, I just realized you are using id, you want `UserID = Request.QueryString["UserID"];`

Comment: @kk1076 You didn't do what I said.. Change id to UserID